# make_server() check if bind to port succeeded

Tags: python, httpserver, wsgiref

*In Python 2 and 3k*, using `wsgi.simple_server.make_server(host, port, app)` does not raise an exception when the port is already in used. Instead, a call to `.server_forever()` or `.handle_request()` simply blocks until the other port closes and the next connection is incoming.

```
import wsgiref.simple_server as simple_server

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/html')])
    return ["<html><body><p>Hello!</p></body></html>".encode('utf-8')]

def main():
    server = simple_server.make_server('', 8901, application)
    server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I would expect an Exception to be raised, since `socket.socket.bind()` also raises an exception in this case. Is there a way to determine if the returned `HTTPServer` did successfully bind to the specified port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for this. The `HTTPServer` class source code in Python 2.7.8 is the following:

```
class HTTPServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):

    allow_reuse_address = 1    # Seems to make sense in testing environment

    def server_bind(self):
        """Override server_bind to store the server name."""
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
        host, port = self.socket.getsockname()[:2]
        self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
        self.server_port = port
```

And `allow_reuse_address` is used in `SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind()` like this:

```
class TCPServer(BaseServer):

    # ...

    def server_bind(self):
        """Called by constructor to bind the socket.

        May be overridden.

        """
        if self.allow_reuse_address:
            self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
        self.server_address = self.socket.getsockname()
```

Setting `allow_reuse_address` to `False` will cause `self.socket.bind(self.server_address)` to raise an exception. I wonder if this line in the `HTTPServer` class is intentional, since the comment says it's "makes sense in testing environments".

Comment: Do you find a way to unset this option, or easily let make_server raise an exception when the port is in use? Thank you!